# How to create a list of paragraphs not linked to a node

Tags: 8, paragraphs

Is there a way to create/edit several paragraphs (from within a UI) and use them grammatically by after.

Here is my use case:

I have a paragraph type made of 3 fields:

- Unit Source : taxonomy term reference (Kg, g, piece, box of
  tomatoes,...)
- Unit target : idem
- Conversion factor: floating number

And I would like to encode some data like

- Unit source = box of tomatoes
- Unit target = kg
- Conversion factor = 3

(A box of tomatoes is equal to 3kg of tomatoes)

I would like to be able

1- to encode through a UI a list of those conversion data

2- to be able to call them in some other function by after.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. By concept paragraphs are always tied to a parent entity, just like normal fields. If it can exist on it's own, better use a node instead.